# I cannot seem to find the correct formatting spec for preceding zeroes in python

Tags: python, string, formatting, int

When adding decimal places, it's as simple as

```
john = 2
johnmod = format(john, '.2f')
print(johnmod)
```

and I get 2.00 back, as expected. But, what's the format spec for adding preceding zeros? I would like for the output to be 0002, and the only spec I've found with Google for that is using %04d, which did not work. If it matters, I am running Python 3.3 on windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several Pythonic ways to do this,:

First using the [string formatting minilanguage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), using your attempted method, first zero means the fill, the 4 means to which width:

```
>>> format(2, "04")
'0002'
```

Also, the format minilanguage:

```
>>> '{0:04}'.format(2)
'0002'
```

the specification comes after the `:`, and the `0` means fill with zeros and the `4` means a width of four.

New in [Python 3.6 are formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals):

```
>>> two = 2 
>>> f'{two:04}'
'0002'
```

Finally, the `str.zfill` method is custom made for this:

```
>>> str(2).zfill(4)
'0002'
```

Comment: Are you kidding me? I just added an unneeded percent sign? Thanks!

Comment: @TimeWillTell Actually, the d and the > were unnecessary too.

Answer (score 2):

Use `zfill`:

```
john = 2
johnmod = str(john).zfill(4)
print(johnmod) # Prints: 0002
```

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there:

```
johnmod = format(john, "04d")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
format(john, '05.2f')
```

You can add the leading `0` to a floating point `f` format as well, but you must add the trailing digits (2) and the decimal point to the total.

Comment: Nice, so to clarify your example, for 2 digits left of the decimal point, plus the decimal point, plus 2 digits after the decimal point, you need to specify 5 (= 2 + 1 + 2)?